# Can Google Maps API V3 be displayed in a table cell instead of a div?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps API V3 Developer's Guide provides us with a following default code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
  }
</script>
```

and

```
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
```

However I would like my map to be displayed in a table cell instead of a div, like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td width="700px" height="700px" id="map_canvas"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The map does not want to show the code above. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: The map does not want to show using the code above*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't put the div inside the table like:

```
<table> 
  <tr>  
    <td width="700px" height="700px">
      <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I must have been typing something wrong, because I copied your code and it works. Thank you for the answer and sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

The style has to be defined with width and height for the `<div>` element; otherwise, the div is zero-height, or so it seems.  Mine didn't work until I put `style='width:100%;height:100%'` in there.